# Creating Blank ImageMosaic Store with REST API and JDBC Catalog

Tags: geoserver

Hello Geoserver Community,
I am currently working on setting up an Image Mosaic store using Geoservers REST API. My goal is to create a blank mosaic that I can later populate with imagery. I have the gesoerver catalog using jdbc. I am attempting to create the imagemosaic by zipping and uploaidng the .properties files through the REST API.

The issue I am having when attempting this is related to geoserver not being able to auto-configure the coverage. I believe the issue has to do with the image mosaic not including any images. I have tried including a sample image as a part of the zip file. Before switching over to having the geoserver catalog in the database this approach worked. I was able to use the rest api to create an image mosaic when the catalog was using the file system. I was able to do this by having the zip file include the properties files and a sample_image file as well. However I am now getting the below issues when trying to create the image mosaic with jdbc configured

1.) This is the error I received when I included the sample_image in my zip file and tried creating the image mosaic

```
ERROR [org.geoserver.rest] - Error auto-configuring coverage
org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Error auto-configuring coverage

Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.add(Unknown Source)

Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         ... 137 more
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: ---- Debugging information ----
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: cause-exception     : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: cause-message       : Illegal grid range [0 .. -222,223] for dimension 0.
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: class               : org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: required-type       : org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: converter-type      : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$GridGeometry2DConverter
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: line number         : 54
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: class[1]            : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: required-type[1]    : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: converter-type[1]   : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$CoverageInfoConverter
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: version             : 2.24.1
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: -------------------------------
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2085)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4011)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4919)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.jdbcconfig.internal.ConfigDatabase.getById(ConfigDatabase.java:1111)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.jdbcconfig.internal.ConfigDatabase.add(ConfigDatabase.java:588)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:        at org.geoserver.jdbcconfig.internal.ConfigDatabase$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dd464281.invoke(<generated>)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.jdbcconfig.internal.ConfigDatabase$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92ee07d1.add(<generated>)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.jdbcconfig.catalog.JDBCCatalogFacade.addInternal(JDBCCatalogFacade.java:911)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.jdbcconfig.catalog.JDBCCatalogFacade.add(JDBCCatalogFacade.java:203)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.IsolatedCatalogFacade.add(IsolatedCatalogFacade.java:115)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         ... 141 more
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: ---- Debugging information ----
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: cause-exception     : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: cause-message       : Illegal grid range [0 .. -222,223] for dimension 0.
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: class               : org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: required-type       : org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: converter-type      : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$GridGeometry2DConverter
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: line number         : 54
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: class[1]            : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: required-type[1]    : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: converter-type[1]   : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$CoverageInfoConverter
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: version             : 2.24.1
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: -------------------------------
F
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdoma
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal grid range [0 .. -222,223] for dimension 0.
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GeneralGridEnvelope.checkCoherence(GeneralGridEnvelope.java:81)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GeneralGridEnvelope.<init>(GeneralGridEnvelope.java:329)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GeneralGridEnvelope.<init>(GeneralGridEnvelope.java:347)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$GridGeometry2DConverter.unmarshal(XStreamPersister.java:1566)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
Feb 07 16:51:47 centos8s.localdomain geoserver[63507]:         ... 206 more
```

2. I then tried taking the sample image out and creating the image mosaic with just the .properties files in the zip. I then received this error which seems to be caused by the lack of a sample image

```
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: 2024-02-06 16:13:13,212 WARN [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path /data/geoserver_data/data/ngs/highres/sample_image
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: 2024-02-06 16:13:13,212 WARN [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path file:/data/geoserver_data/data/ngs/highres/datastore.properties
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: 2024-02-06 16:13:13,302 ERROR [org.geoserver.rest] - Error auto-configuring coverage
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Error auto-configuring coverage
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:286)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:292)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at com.ngs.geoserver.custom.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:97)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at com.ngs.geoserver.custom.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:89)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:319)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:273)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to acquire test coverage and image layout for format:ImageMosaic
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:988)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:979)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.configureCoverageInfo(CoverageStoreFileController.java:329)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:277)
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: ... 130 more
    Feb 06 16:13:13 centos7.localdomain geoserver[20142]: 2024-02-06 16:13:13,306 INFO [com.ngs.geoserver.custom.RequestLoggingFilter] - 127.0.0.1 anonymous PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/ngs/coveragestores/highres/file.imagemosaic Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.21) status:500 size: unknown mime: text/plain took 1256ms
```

I tried creating an image mosaic store both including a sample image and not including a sample image. I received two different errors with auto configure.